# why meteor subscribed collection is not accessible in angular function

Tags: angularjs, meteor, angular-meteor

I am developing some application with meteor and use angular for the ui, the collection named 'Foods' is accessible in the loop but it's not accessible in function openfooda and I could not figure out why.

```
for (var i=0; i<FoodCategories.find().count(); i++) {
        $scope.groups[i] = {
            name: FoodCategories.find().fetch()[i]['title'],
            items: [],
            show : true,
        };

        for (var j=0; j < Foods.find({cat:i+1}).count(); j++) {
            $scope.groups[i].items.push({
                name:''+Foods.find({cat:i+1}).fetch()[j]['name'],
                id:''+Foods.find({cat:i+1}).fetch()[j]['id']});

        }

    }

    /**
     * this function opens a modal for getting user nutrition log
     */
    $scope.openfood = function(foodId){
        $scope.selectedfood = Foods.findOne({id : foodId});
        console.log(Foods.find().count());
        console.log(Foods.findOne({id : foodId}));
        $scope.unit = FoodUnits.findOne({id : $scope.selectedfood.unit})['title'] ;
        $scope.modal.show();
    }
```

Comment: Do you have access to window? is window['Foods'] working?

Answer (score 0):

try to subscribe to collection first
this.subscribe()
in your case
this.subsribe('foods')